# Azure Functions for Splunk

Tags: azure, azure-functions, splunk, azure-eventhub

I am trying to set up Azure functions for Splunk
The steps are shown as below. After the Azure function has been deployed, I could actually see from the app service plan interface with the data in & out figure.However, from the splunk side, I was told that they do not receive any data (I do not have the access right to splunk)
My question is: From where can I know if my settings for Azure function for splunk is working ? as I see it is running and there is changing in data-in and data-out volume...

The steps that I followed

1. In Azure, configure the diagnostics profiles of the resources that you want to monitor.
2. In Splunk, switch on the HEC port and get the token value.
3. Gather the settings below.
4. Click the "Deploy to Azure" button below.
   https://github.com/sebastus/AzureFunctionDeployment/tree/SplunkVS
5. Authenticate to the Azure Portal (if necessary)
6. Fill in the form with the setting values
7. Wait a few minutes for the function to be created and deployed
   8 In the Splunk UI, watch for events to appear.

Comment: You could check the logs for your function in application insights for errors. Also, did you follow the [security note](https://github.com/microsoft/AzureFunctionForSplunkVS#important-security-note) in the repo.